# How can I parse XML while keeping the original order of the word in php?

Tags: php, xml, xml-parsing

How can I parse xml similar to the one shown here, while keeping the order of the original words? My aim is to extract only the content of the first `<span>`-tag and the `<strong>`-tag, but the order of words should stay the same (output should be: The Bank for International Settlements [BIZ]). I tried it using the built-in php parsers (XML DOM and SimpleXML - Get), however I wasn't able to keep the order of words.

```
<span class="full_collocation">
    the<strong class="tilde">Bank</strong> for International Settlements
</span> 
<span class="full_collocation">
    [<span class="or"><acronym title="or">or</acronym></span> BIZ]
</span>
```

Comment: [How about stripping all HTML tags?](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strip-tags.php)

Comment: I do not want to keep the rest, in this case the "or"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With DOMDocument, you should be able to easily get the value you want. Check out this example:

```
$xmlString = '<root>
  <span class="full_collocation">
    the<strong class="tilde">Bank</strong> for International Settlements
  </span>
  <span class="full_collocation">
    [<span class="or"><acronym title="or">or</acronym></span> BIZ]
  </span>
</root>';

$dom = new DOMDocument();
$dom->loadXML($xmlString);
foreach($dom->documentElement->childNodes as $childNode) {
    echo trim($childNode->textContent); // prints "theBank for International Settlements" and "[or BIZ]"
}
```

Comment: This is was I was able to achieve, however the word "bank" is lost in the process, which is needed.

Comment: This is very helpful, but is there a way to only output the content of certain tags? In my case, the span-tags that are immediate children of the root-tag and all strong tags? (I do not want the "or")

Comment: You can use [DomXPath::query](http://php.net/manual/en/domxpath.query.php) to target specific elements of your DOM (similar to CSS). Once you have all the nodes that match your query, simply call `textContent` on them. Alternatively, you can do the parsing yourself to find the nodes followed by/not followed by, etc.